# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment: I am not sure what is causing this error?

Tags: javascript, class

I have a `class Employee` that I have imported into a new js file (Main.js) that has an array of objects of a list of employees, but I get an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` I have attached where I get the error in the console log.

As you can see in the HTML file I have the `type = module` for both scripts

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="module" src="classes.js" defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Javascript Practice</title>
</head>
```

Classes.js file

```
export class Employee{
    constructor(
        id,
        name,
        surname,
        jobtitle,
        salary,
        startDate
        ){
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
       this.surname = surname;
       this.jobtitle = jobtitle;
       this.salary = salary;
       this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

Main.js file

```
import { Employee } from "../classes.js"

const employees =[
    new Employee = {
        id:id,
        name:"Paul",
        surname:"Jakens",
        jobtitle:"Senior Salesmen",
        salary: 13000,
        startDate:"2015/05/15"
    },
    new Employee = {
        id:id,
        name:"Susan",
        surname:"Lupan",
        jobtitle:"Junior Designer",
        salary: 12000,
        startDate:"2021/03/16"
    },
    new Employee = {
        id:id,
        name:"John",
        surname:"Angel",
        jobtitle:"Senior Full Stack Developer",
        salary: 40000,
        startDate:"2014/10/18"
    },
]
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kecz8.jpg)

Comment: The correct syntax is `new Employ(id, "John", "Angel", "Senior Full Stack Developer", 40000, "2014/10/18")`. You don't name the arguments, that arguments align with the parameters in the constructor definition in your class

Comment: new Employee = {…} should be new Employee(…). And the answer from @NickParsons was better. Personally I prefer the object based arcs but you tried to pass object args to a function that takes positional args. Convert to positional or object based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the employee is a class instead of an object, I think you have to call the constructor.

So this should be what the employees would look like

```js
const employees = [
  new Employee(id,"Paul","Jakens","Senior Salesmen", 13000,"2015/05/15")
  ...
]
```

Also you can remove the id from the constructor since you're randomizing it

```js
constructor(
        name,
        surname,
        jobtitle,
        salary,
        startDate
        ){
       this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + (new Date()).getTime();;
       this.name = name;
       this.surname = surname;
       this.jobtitle = jobtitle;
       this.salary = salary;
       this.startDate = startDate;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I got confused between objects and parameters there.

Comment: Just another one DominicValerio, I tested it, the ```id``` should be taken about of the ```new Employee(id,"Paul","Jakens","Senior Salesmen", 13000,"2015/05/15")``` as the id automatically populates on its own from the ```this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + (new Date()).getTime();```